# Batch / CMD script to delete folder but excluding more than one

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In advance: I'm new to batch or programming in general so please explain as much as possible.

My problem:
I want to delete all folders **not** named *X* and *Y* in a directory Z (ex. D:\Test\z)

So let's say Z contains these folder:

- backup
- resources
- project1
- project2
- project3

I'd need to exclude only *backup* and *resources* from deletion via a script.
I looked up multiple soultions for not deleting only **one** folder with a certain name but I don't know if it's possible for multiple values with Batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested:

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=C:\Z"
set "exclude_list=backup resources"
pushd "%root_dir%"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /a:d^| findstr /v "%exclude_list%"') do (
   echo rd /s /q "%%~f#"
)
```

if this looks ok delete the `echo` on the last line to activate deletion.

If all folders you want to delete are like `project*` you can try also :

```
for /d %%a in ("project*") do rd /s /q "%%~fa"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked just fine.  Could you by any chance explain the script in detail?

Comment: This method have two problems: it requires exact case match in order to find the folder names (that is easily solved adding `/I` ignore case switch in `findstr` command), and it also exclude folders that partially match any name in the exclude list. For example, it also would exclude `backup1`, `backupA`, `backupETC` folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define working variables
set "dir=D:\Test\z"
set "exclude=/backup/resources/"

rem Change current dir to working dir
cd /D "%dir%"
rem Process all folders in this dir
for /D %%f in (*) do (
   rem If current folder is not in "exclude" var
   if "!exclude:/%%f/=!" equ "%exclude%" (
      rem Delete it
      ECHO rd /s /q "%%f"
   )
)
```

This method use internal cmd.exe commands only, so it run faster than other methods that may use external .exe files (like `findstr.exe`).

The way to detect if a name is in the exclude variable is trying to delete such name from it: `"%exclude:/%%f/=%"`: if the result is equal to the original variable contents, the folder was *not* there. This method is very simple and efficient and works not matter the case of the letters, so it don't requires any `/I` ignore case switch in the `if` command.

The names are delimited by slashes to avoid any problem caused by partial name matches; for this reason the `%%f` part is enclosed in slashes in the `if` command.

Note that the value of `%%f` change *in each iteration* of the `for` command. For this reason, the `exclude` variable is surrounded by exclamation marks instead percent signs and the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command is given at beginning; otherwise, the %expansion% would be done just *one time*, before the `for` command start iterations. You may look for "delayed expansion" in this forum for a further explanation of this point.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and this specific solution. The solution provided by npocmaka was doing it's job for my usecase but I'll adapt the script to be more fool-proof and applicable for future usecases.